# asp.net, showing the content of two contentplaceholder in different divs at the same time

Tags: asp.net

I'm using asp.net, is there a way to show two contents of different aspx pages in parallel? (meaning showing each caontent, using contentplaceholder, in different div)

Comment: Yes, by using iframes... Or Ajax to load each page separately and place a section of their contents within the DIVs you're targetting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also achieve the requested functionality using the RadSplitter control and its ContentUrl property. See these demos for more information: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/splitter/examples/externalcontentloading/defaultcs.aspx and http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/splitter/examples/showcontentduringload/defaultcs.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple placeholders.

Example...

Site.Master
...

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Default.aspx

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="Server">
```